# How to stop tedious connection pool logging

Tags: node.js, tedious

I am using tedious connection pool in my Node js application. Everything is working fine but I see unnecessary logs in console.
How to get rid of these log messages. I want to see logs only if anything fails.

Logs:

```
Tedious-Connection-Pool: filling pool with 2
Tedious-Connection-Pool: creating connection: 1
Tedious-Connection-Pool: creating connection: 2
Tedious-Connection-Pool: filling pool with 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `poolConfig` that you pass to `new ConnectionPool` so that it contains the key `log: false`

Also see the example in the documentation https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious-connection-pool where `log: true` appears.